# Facebook publish permission - posting from server

Tags: android, facebook, permissions

In my app I ask user first basic permissions first and publish when required. Client itself doesn't do anything with accessToken it just pass it to server.

1) After getting basic permissions client immediately send it to server.
2) Problem starts when client asks for publish permissions. Once user grants publish permission my session still shows old basic permissions. But if same time I check users settings on fb it shows that app has granted publish permissions. But somehow in app I am not getting
 updated accessToken.

this is what i do for publish permission

```
private void requestPublishPermissions(Session session) {
    if (session != null) {
        Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSION)
                // demonstrate how to set an audience for the publish permissions,
                // if none are set, this defaults to FRIENDS
                .setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS)
                .setRequestCode(REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE);
        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
    }
}
```

once user granted permission ( when this method is called) just next  Session.StatusCallback after this method call still shows me old session permissions.

My Question:
1) How to get refreshed accessToken immediately after publish permisison is approves?
2) If (1) is not possible then what is right way of doing it? because call from client has to be with 
updated accessToken. Do make user wait till we get updated accessToken? if yes How?

Thanks.

Comment: Finally I figured it out. I Will post complete solution once I test it completely.

Answer (score 2):

*Answering My Own Question*

After spending hours and hours figured it out. Here step-by-step process of of asking read and publish permissions

**Setup** Eclipse, Android, Facebook SDK 3.6
**Program** MainActivity and Static Fragment
**Trying to Achieve?**  Asking read permissions and then publish permissions.

***MainActivity***

```
public class YourFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Static Fragment
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_layout);
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
}
```

***YourFragment.java***

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {
public static String TAG = YourFragment.class.getSimpleName();

private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_stream, publish_actions");

// Flag to represent if we are waiting for extended permissions

private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();
private Session.StatusCallback publishCallback = new PublishCallback();

private Button publish;



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

    buttonLoginLogout = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonLoginLogout);
    publish = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.publish);


            //Make Sure you have session when you instantiate fragment
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session == null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            session = Session.restoreSession(getActivity(), null, statusCallback, savedInstanceState);
        }
        if (session == null) {
            session = new Session(getActivity());
        }
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
        }
    }

    onSessionStateChange();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(statusCallback);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Session.getActiveSession().removeCallback(statusCallback);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(getActivity(), requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    Session.saveSession(session, outState);
}

private void onSessionStateChange() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if(session.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions")){

                 //You got you updated token here with extended permissions
    }
    if (session.isOpened()) {

                 //Do you stuff here. e.g Getting accessToken, expiry etc.

    }
    else {
    }
}

public  void requestPublishPermissions(Activity activity, Session session, List<String> permissions, int requestCode) {

    if (session != null) {
        Session.NewPermissionsRequest reauthRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(activity, permissions).setRequestCode(requestCode);
        reauthRequest.setCallback(publishCallback);

        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(reauthRequest);
    }
}

    //Set this on onclick call of some button in you fragment
private void openForRead() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
    }
    else {
        Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), this, true, statusCallback);
    }
}

    //Set this on onclick call of some logout button in you fragment 
private void logMeOut() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (!session.isClosed()) {
        session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
    }
}

private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange();
        Debug.waitForDebugger();
        if (exception != null){
                            //Handel your exception case here 
            Log.i(TAG, exception.getMessage());
                    }
    }
}

private class PublishCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        Debug.waitForDebugger();
        onSessionStateChange();
        if (exception != null){
                            //Handel your exception case here
            Log.i(TAG, exception.getMessage());
                     }
    }
}
}
```

***Errors you might encounter***

- **1) publish permission never callsback**

This is the most annoying one. When user grant publish permission callback never returns but the same
time if you user sees its app setting page in FB it shows that user has granted publish permission
to you app. In such scenario, technically we can use same accessToken which we have received in readForOpen call because most of the times accessToken doesn't change even after successful callbacks (Isn't it a flaw). But we cannot rely on this as FB can change accessToken anytime.

***How to avoid this?***
-- Make sure onActivityResult is there in both your Fragment and main Activity. And calling Session.onActivityResult

-- Make sure you are setting a publish callback to newRequest. FB picks callback instance back from NewPermissionsRequest using addCallback(newPermissionsRequest.getCallback());

- **2) User logged in as different Facebook user**

Interestingly, FB SDK shows this only when you ask for publish permission. Internally FB sdk validates fbid by making a "me" call an compare response (return could be null) with previous (existing session fbid) one and if there is a difference between these two SDK shows this error.

***How to avoid this?***
-- Make sure you have setup your FB application correctly specially package name.
-- This one made me insane. DO NOT USE PROXY. while using proxy android phone somehow FB SDK's internal "ME" call to validate FBIDs fails with error com.facebook.FacebookException: could not construct request body and graph user becomes null and hence this error. Though is is kind of weird because I am using fiddler which is normal intercepting proxy

I hope this will help.